# Appropriate-Word use

Tags: word-usage

I have a hydraulic model which I want to use for a new study, 
I want to say that I need to check the extend of my model to find out if it is neither big nor small for the new study. How can I say that in a formal report? I have used the word **appropriate**.  Is it correct?

The extend of the model will be reviewed to make sure if it is appropriate for the current study.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Appropriate** is a very good and safe word in a professional setting.  If you use it, you are saying it's a model that will do a good job in this application.

I would suggest some other synonyms, but I am not able to understand some of your other language.  You have some serious problems.  For example, **extend** is a verb, not an adjective that can be applied to a model.  **Extent** is a similar word, but it's a noun.  You need to replace this word with one that makes sense in your context.

It sounds like this is a theoretical model.  But you use the words **big** and **small**, which are normally reserved for physical objects.

In order to help you we need more information: Is this model a physical object or a theory?  What is it about this model that would make it appropriate or inappropriate for your application?  It's size?  Complexity?

Comment: Thank's Farnsy for your response. It is a computer model . It is neither Physical nor theoretical model. Thank's again